# ran out of space on disc? still have 30gb free

Tags: gparted

I tried to install steam and ubuntu told me I only had a few megs left. but my partition says it has 30gb free.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb5       6.9G  6.3G  236M  97% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            1.9G   12K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           396M  1.2M  395M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G   89M  1.9G   5% /run/shm
none            100M   52K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sdb1       138G  130G  8.7G  94% /media/randy/New Volume
/dev/sda1        75G   48G   27G  64% /media/randy/F440B04040B00B7E
```

Comment: can you append the output of `df -h` to your question please?

Comment: Your root partition says it has 236MB left, not 30GB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A certain amount of disk space will be reserved for the: [root user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7950/reserved-space-for-root-on-a-filesystem-why) so that that user will always be able to function even if regular users are erroring because of no space.  A secondary reason for the reservation is that the file-system itself requires a certain amount of free space to operate correctly.  This is related to why Linux file-systems do not need to be defragmented and Windows file-systems do.  The way the files are laid out on Linux systems means that fragmenting: [does not occur](http://www.howtogeek.com/115229/htg-explains-why-linux-doesnt-need-defragmenting/) as long as there is a certain amount of free space.

Comment: That was very informative. but it didn't really help me figure out why I can't install steam.

Comment: It answered your question.  You are out of space for regular users.  See the first link, it mentions the command to unreserve that space: `tune2fs`.  However, if you persist in making the system do what you want instead of what it should you ARE going to cause issues for yourself later.  Your choice.

Comment: then if I should not be doing that why would you tell me to?

Comment: I said that it is possible to unreserve that space but that it is a bad idea.  A better idea is to uninstall something you don't use or even better install a bigger disk.  The `tune2fs` command is for advanced users.  If you know what you are doing you can override file-system parameters because you know the consequences.  Since you didn't even know about the command it probably isn't a good idea for yourself.  Regardless, in a terminal type `man tune2fs` to read about it.  You can make it so that only 5GB is reserved, instead of 30GB, and that should still be fine.

Comment: But, then, still, when you go to install Steam games you are still going to need space.  Unless you are using Steam In-Home Streaming to stream them from another Windows machine on the same network.

Comment: well the disk has close to 30gb free I don't see why I would need to uninstall anything. infact that's what I did when it first popped up, I switched over to windows and uninstalled and deleted a boatload of stuff.

Comment: See the other answer: your Windows partition is separate from your Linux partition.  Your Linux root (/) is full.  The Windows partition cannot be used as your Linux root space so no matter how much you free there it won't change your situation.  Also, disregard my `tune2fs` advice - I should have read your `df` output more closely.  You will need to uninstall Linux programs to make more free space, not Windows ones.

Comment: so what you're saying is I should just wipe the whole damn thing since I don't intend to use windows anymore?

Comment: You are out of space.  I'm not saying you should do anything.  However, if you have no need for Windows then properly planning your partitions and what you need to do to get them right would be a worthy effort.  If `/dev/sdb` is a permanent drive then it might be good to make that all your `/` mountpoint.  The `/` mountpoint includes `/home` and within home is your user folder and within that Steam will store your downloaded games.  If everything is `/` then all your space can be used for whatever is needed. Having separate partitions however is useful for reinstalls so you can keep some.

Comment: well I am and I'm not. my second drive is 150gb and what I use for all of my steam games on windows. I literally just need to wipe that drive and steal, say, 10gb from my windows partition and I would be golden. if that's even possible. I have no idea. I installed ubuntu literally 2 days ago

Comment: If they are the same physical disk then you can try http://gparted.org/ download that iso and burn it to a disc. Then boot from that disc and resize your partitions. Have backups of everything important in case it goes south. If they aren't the same physical disk then you have much fewer options.  In that case you can have one disc as your `/` mountpoint and the bigger disk as your `/home` mountpoint - where Steam will store games. You may have to rearrange cables to your hard drives so one boots before the other. Also, without Windows you can't play your Windows-only games in Steam.

Comment: seperate HDD. no cdroms and no spare usbsticks. the only one I have currently has an ubuntu livecd on it. so I don't know if i can put Gparted on there. there is literally nothing important. the closest thing I have to important is my borderlands 2 saves

Comment: Don't do it then. You want at least one Ubuntu installation disc and one gparted disc at the same time.  The gparted to try to resize the partitions, and then if that fails then the Ubuntu one to reinstall from scratch.  If you only have gparted and it borks the disks then you are left without any method to get any operating system onto your computer.

Answer (score 2):

Note these lines:

```
/dev/sdb5       6.9G  6.3G  236M  97% /
/dev/sdb1       138G  130G  8.7G  94% /media/randy/New Volume
/dev/sda1        75G   48G   27G  64% /media/randy/F440B04040B00B7E
```

The first line is important. That shows how much space your Ubuntu installation has in its root partition. As you can see, it has very little (not that it had much to begin with). That you have 30G free elsewhere (in `/media/randy/F440B04040B00B7E` - an NTFS partition, by the looks of it) doesn't help Ubuntu all that much.